# Show custom success message in WooCommerce MyAccount

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a custom function to the WooCommerce MyAccount page. When I press a button an Ajax function gets called which triggers a PHP file. In this PHP file I've tried to set a custom success message:

```
wc_add_notice( 'Zwei-Faktor-Authentifizierung erfolgreich aktiviert.', 'success' );
```

I do this at the end of the PHP file. Then I check in my JS file if all was successful:

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function () {
    }).success(function () {
        var link = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/my-account/"
        window.location.href = link;
    }).fail(function (data) {

        // jQuery('.woocommerce-job-action-table-container .blockUI').addClass('invisible');
    });
```

As you can see I'm doing a redirect when the function was successful. I'm redirecting to the MyAccount page after this. On this page I expect the custom notice but I can't see any message. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Can you post your PHP file which has custom message ?

Comment: You can find in the my-account.php following code: wc_print_notices(); 
So I expect the custom message on each account site I redirect. You understand what I'll do?

Comment: Test if the notice is set correctly by calling `wc_print_notices()` in the triggered PHP and return the output to your Ajax function (`console.log()` the response to check contents for the notice). If it's not there, it's not set properly. If it is, check if the notices don't get cleared somewhere else in the meantime. (Like at the end of the triggered PHP file or something.)

Comment: Also check if the triggered PHP can access the `WP()` session. The file should have some WP session init before you can use `wp_add_notice()` (see http://hookr.io/functions/wc_add_notice/).